# camera angle movement control enable and disable in three js?

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js

I used orbit controls. I created 2 buttons `enable` and `disable`. `controls.rotate=false` this not working. Below my code. What mistake I did?

```
camera3D = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(angle, width / height, near, far);
        camera3D.position.set(0, 10, 500);

        controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera3D, renderer3D.domElement );
        controls.rotateSpeed = 0.50;
        controls.zoomSpeed = 1.2;

this.disableMode = function(){
            console.log('disable work');
            controls.enabled = false;
            controls.rotate = false;
            controls.update();

        }
```

Comment: I guess it should be `controls.enableRotate = false;`.

Comment: `controls.enableRotate = false; ` it's also not disable mode.rotate my camera angle @Mugen87

Comment: Are you using the latest version of `three.js` and `OrbitControls`?

Comment: yes, I think the latest version.

Comment: Can you please demonstrate the issue with this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/4062/ . I've already included `OrbitControls` for you.

Comment: Thank you@Mugen87

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is setup minPolarAngle & maxPolarAngle to the same values.

Try this one :

```
var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, DOMElement);

// controls.addEventListener( 'change', render ); // call this only in static scenes 
// (i.e., if there is no animation loop)

controls.enableDamping = true; 
// an animation loop is required when either damping or auto-rotation are enabled

controls.dampingFactor = 0.05;
controls.screenSpacePanning = true;
controls.minDistance = 22;
controls.maxDistance = 115;

// Angle in radians

// this can be used to fix your problem.
// Just setup to 0 or any other angle you needed...
// Must bve same value `minPolarAngle` and `maxPolarAngle`.

controls.minPolarAngle = 0; // 1.5 * Math.PI / 12; 
controls.maxPolarAngle = 0; // 1.5 * Math.PI / 3;

controls.minAzimuthAngle = - Math.PI / 2;
controls.maxAzimuthAngle = - Math.PI / 2;

controls.target.set(1, 4, -8.5);
```